# Correct way to define Python source code encoding

Tags: python, encoding

[PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) defines how to declare Python source code encoding. Normally, the first 2 lines of a Python file should start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
```

But I have seen a lot of files starting with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: <encoding name> -*-
```

I.e., it says `encoding` rather than `coding`.

How should the file encoding be declared?

---

<sub>Please use ["SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ..." or "SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with ..." trying to use non-ASCII text in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620) to close duplicate questions about syntax errors resulting from a missing or faulty encoding declaration. This question, on the other hand, is the canonical for questions about how the declaration is written and whether it is necessary.</sub>

Comment: By the way, for more flexibility and portability it is recommended to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I love the way none of the answers on this page have a simple, working example for say UTF8. StackOverly at its finest.

Comment: I just wanted to add that Python 3 has changed the default encoding from `ascii` to `UTF-8`. Compare: [python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding) with [python 3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding). This means you can safely omit this encoding if you wanted to specify `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Check the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations):

"If a comment in the first or second line of the Python script matches the regular expression `coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+)`, this comment is processed as an encoding declaration"

"The recommended forms of this expression are

```
# -*- coding: <encoding-name> -*-
```

which is recognized also by GNU Emacs, and

```
# vim:fileencoding=<encoding-name>
```

which is recognized by Bram Moolenaar’s VIM."

So, you can put pretty much anything before the "coding" part, but stick to "coding" (with no prefix) if you want to be 100% python-docs-recommendation-compatible.

More specifically, you need to use whatever is recognized by Python *and the specific editing software you use* (if it needs/accepts anything at all). E.g. the `coding` form is recognized (out of the box) by GNU Emacs but not Vim (yes, without a universal agreement, it's essentially a [turf war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turf_war)).

Comment: The `-*-` ensures that the line is recognised by GNU Emacs (a text editor popular with some programmers). Note that, contrary to this answer, both the Emacs form and the Vim form are 100% python-docs-recommendation-compatible (as they both match the regexp - "match", by long-standing convention, means "match anywhere in the string", contrary to Python's API).

Comment: The specific Emacs requirements to embedded directives are documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specify-Coding.html . In brief, the format for the start of the file is: `<prefix>-*- var: value[; ...] -*-`.

Answer (score 43):

PEP 263:

> the first or second line must match
>   the regular
>       expression "coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)"

So, "en**coding: UTF-8**" matches.

PEP provides some examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
```

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os, sys
```

Answer (score 42):

Just copy paste below statement on the top of your program.It will solve character encoding problems

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 5):

#### As of today — June 2018

---

[PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) itself mentions the regex it follows:

> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into
>   the source files either as first or second line in the file, such as:
>
> ```
> # coding=<encoding name>
> ```
>
> or (using formats recognized by popular editors):
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
> ```
>
> More precisely, the first or second line must match the following regular expression:
>
> ```
> ^[ \t\f]*#.*?coding[:=][ \t]*([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)
> ```

So, as already summed up by other answers, it'll match `coding` with any prefix, but if you'd like to be as PEP-compliant as it gets (even though, as far as I can tell, using `encoding` instead of `coding` does not violate PEP 263 in any way) — stick with 'plain' `coding`, with no prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is similar to Ruby - either method is okay.

This is largely because different text editors use different methods (ie, these two) of marking encoding.

With Ruby, as long as the first, or second if there is a shebang line contains a string that matches:

```
coding: encoding-name
```

and ignoring any whitespace and other fluff on those lines.  (It can often be a = instead of :, too).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the original proposal for source file encodings was to use a regular expression for the first couple of lines, which would allow both.

I think the regex was something along the lines of `coding:` followed by something.

I found this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
Which is the original proposal, but I can't seem to find the final spec stating exactly what they did.

I've certainly used `encoding:` to great effect, so obviously that works.

Try changing to something completely different, like `duhcoding: ...` to see if that works just as well.