# Typecasting to unicode string?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm going through the djangobook and in one of the examples the author writes this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Does the "u" in front of '%s %s' turn the string into unicode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't quite 'turn' the string to unicode, it represents a unicode-string. To quote the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

> In Python source code, Unicode literals are written as strings
>   prefixed with the ‘u’ or ‘U’ character
>   ...
>   Ideally, you’d want to be able to write literals in your language’s natural encoding. You could then
>   edit Python source code with your favorite editor which would display
>   the accented characters naturally, and have the right characters used
>   at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that `u` prefix means that the string is Unicode. There is one more thing to know - you should declare the source code encoding so that Python knows how to deal with the string:

http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

[Correct way to define Python source code encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator will create a new string using the given string as a format. Since you've used a leading `u` this string will be Unicode. Each `%s` will cause the argument to be converted into Unicode as well before it is inserted into the new string.