# Define shebang and encoding in python

Tags: python, encoding, shebang, env

Is there a difference between

(a) **defining the encoding with the shebang**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

(b) **defining the shebang and the encoding on separate lines**?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: There are many questions about this already, [here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding) that answers your question.