# Encoding issue for Python tool Unidecode on CL

Tags: python, encoding, command-line, utf-8

I need to convert unicode files to ascii. In case, a letter doesn't exist in ascii, it should be converted to it's closest ascii representation.
I'm using the Unidecode tool for it (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode). It works fine when I use it in the Python interpreter on the CL (thus, by invoking `python` and then importing the libraries and then printing the decoded word like this: `print unidecode(u'äèß')`)

Unfortunately, when I try to use this tool directly on the command line (thus, by doing something like `python -c "from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'äèß')"`, it only prints gibberish (`A$?A"A` to be exact, even though it should've printed (and did in the interpreter) `aess`). This is annoying and I don't know how to solve that issue. I thought it might be due to encoding errors with my Terminal, not being set correctly to utf-8 or something. However, `locale` in my Terminal printed me the following output:

> LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
>
> LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8"

Or, might it be due to Python that has problems with StdIn encoding on the command line? It gave me correct output in the python interpreter, but when invoking `python -c` not.

Do you guys have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type 'äèß' in the terminal, although you see 'äèß', the terminal sees bytes. If your terminal encoding is `utf-8`, then it sees the bytes

```
In [2]: 'äèß'
Out[2]: '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa8\xc3\x9f'
```

So when you type

```
python -c "from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'äèß')"
```

at the command line, the terminal (assuming utf-8 encoding) sees

```
python -c "from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa8\xc3\x9f')"
```

That's not the unicode you intended to send to Python.

```
In [28]: print(u'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa8\xc3\x9f')
Ã¤Ã¨Ã
```

There are a number of ways to work around the problem, perhaps in order of convenience:

1. Let the terminal change `äèß` to `\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa8\xc3\x9f` and then
   decode it as `utf-8`:

   ```
   % python -c "from unidecode import *; print unidecode('äèß'.decode('utf_8'))"
   aess
   ```
2. Declare an encoding as shown in Nehal J. Wani's solution:

   ```
   % python -c "#coding: utf8
   > from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'äèß')" 
   aess
   ```

   This requires writing the command on two lines, however.
3. Since  `u'äèß` is equivalent to `u'\xe4\xe8\xdf'` you could avoid
   the problem by passing `u'\xe4\xe8\xdf'` instead:

   ```
   % python -c "from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'\xe4\xe8\xdf')"
   aess
   ```

   The problem with doing it this way (obviously) is you have to figure
   out the hexadecimal code point values.
4. Or, you could specify the unicode by name:

   ```
   % python -c "from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S}')"
   aess
   ```

Comment: As I will integrate it in a script that does the conversion for a lot of files, 1 seems to be a really good solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you try writing this in a file:

```
#!/bin/python
from unidecode import *
print unidecode(u'äèß')

[Wani@Linux tmp]$ python tmp.py 
File "tmp.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file tmp.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
[Wani@Linux tmp]$
```

To fix this, you do:

```
#!/bin/python
#coding: utf8
from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'äèß')

[Wani@Linux tmp]$ python tmp.py
aeess
[Wani@Linux tmp]$
```

So, you need to call from command-line like this:

```
[Wani@Linux tmp]$ python -c "#coding: utf8
from unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'äèß')"
aeess
[Wani@Linux tmp]$ python -c "$(echo -e "#coding: utf8\nfrom unidecode import *; print unidecode(u'äèß')")"
aeess
[Wani@Linux tmp]
```

Further Reading: [Correct way to define Python source code encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding)

Comment: I didn't know I was able to do this on two lines, cool! For my application, unutbu's solution seems to work, though.