# Python SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file

Tags: python, django

I have just switched from using running a Django App under Python 3 to Using Python 2.7. I now get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/user/Documents/workspace/testpro/testpro/apps/common/models/vendor.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

The code its referring to is just a comment:

```
class Vendor(BaseModel):
    """
    A company manages owns one of more stores.‎
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Why?

**This works:**

```
 class Vendor(BaseModel):
        """

        """
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: Did you read the linked PEP yet?

Comment: You don't have any comments in your posted code. You have a *docstring*.

Comment: Please show the *actual* code that produces that error. The error refers to your source code containing a non-ASCII character, which isn't the case for the snippet of code you posted.

Comment: @LukasGraf: I am trying to locate a codec that might use some kind of non-breaking space at position E2, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @Lukas Graf if I remove the 'docstring' it works.

Comment: @LukasGraf: There is a `\xe2\x80\x8e` sequence in the posted code.

Comment: I just noticed, my bad. @Spike, please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a UTF-8 encoded [U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+200e) in your docstring:

```
'\n    A company manages owns one of more stores.\xe2\x80\x8e\n    '
```

Either remove that codepoint (and try to use a code editor, not a word processor) from your code, or just put the PEP-263 encoding comment at the top of the file:

```
# encoding=utf8
```

Python 3 uses UTF-8 by default, Python 2 defaults to ASCII for source code unless you add that comment.

Answer (score 0):

As already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24118751/8554766) by [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), your docstring contains a UTF-8 (i.e. non-ASCII) character.

I'd like to elaborate a bit, on the proper way to declare file encoding. As it is stated in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into
>   the source files either as first or second line in the file, such as:
>
> ```
> # coding=<encoding name>
> ```
>
> or (using formats recognized by popular editors):
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
> ```
>
> More precisely, the first or second line must match the following regular expression:
>
> ```
> ^[ \t\f]*#.*?coding[:=][ \t]*([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)
> ```

What that means (as it brightly summed up in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729016/8554766)):

> So, you can put pretty much anything before the "coding" part, but stick to "coding" (with no prefix) if you want to be 100% python-docs-recommendation-compatible.

So, for the case, suggested 'magic comments', would be:

```
# coding=utf8
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=utf8 :
```