# Printing urdu (non-latin language) word by word using python

Tags: python, urdu

I am trying to print Urdu words using python. I read about Unicode but the [problem I face is that python tries to print the Urdu just like English, that is, from left to right and character by character. In Urdu characters] cannot be printed like those in English. I have already tried few solutions like the one mentioned [here](http://%3Chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252138/print-urdu-arabic-language-in-console-python%3E) but they didn't work for me. I have been trying to print my Urdu string with the following code.

```
text_string = "آکاش کمار".decode('utf-8')   
print text_string
```

the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNjY9.png) I get on Ubuntu terminal is like English from left to right instead of right to left and that too character by character.

Comment: That's because your terminal doesn't use a proper text layout engine.

Comment: That a problem of the terminal application, more exactly it should print the command prompt LTR and your output RTL. That would result in a large mess especially when both has go in one line. So usually there can be only one direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with Gnome Terminal which does not support bidirectional (i.e., right-to-left or "RTL") text output.  If I run your above program (with an encoding declaration):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text_string = "آکاش کمار".decode('utf-8')
print(text_string)
```

in an Emacs shell buffer (with *does* support mixed LTR and RTL output), I get the correct output:

```
$ python2 urdu.py
آکاش کمار
$
```

However, if I run it in a Gnome Terminal, I get the backwards output that you posted.

If you don't use Emacs, another alternative is to install the `mlterm` (multilingual terminal) package and use the terminal emulator it provides.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the real goal that I was trying to achieve using this thing was to generate images that contain the Urdu text for training a text/non-text Urdu classifier. I followed the same code but instead of printing the output I tried to draw it on a image but I still got the similar issue.

Comment: @NileshKumar: *Again*, layout engine. Use one.

Answer (score 0):

by using LibRaqm your problem can be solved the link to the library is given below
https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm