# Saving a Python 2.7 script that contains Arabic

Tags: python, mysql, tweepy

I'm having a weird issue.  I'm working on a Twitter-Tweepy-MySQL collection project.

I'm totally happy with my script.  If I run it collecting against "#London", for example - no problem.

However, when I try collect on a non-Latin hashtag (eg "#מזל_טוב"), I can't even *save* the script, let alone run it.

I hit Ctrl + S - doesn't save.  I try run the script - I get "Source Must Be Saved Ok to Save?", hit Ok - nothing happens.

This happens with both Arabic and Hebrew hashtags, so I can only think there's a unicode issue here - but when I collect against a Latin hashtag which coincidentally produces non-Latin alphabet results, they're printed & saved to MySQL without a problem.

Very grateful for any pointers.
Robin

Script follows:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import MySQLdb
import time
import json

conn = MySQLdb.connect ('nyub', 'nyub', 'nyub', 'nyub', charset='utf8')

c = conn.cursor()

ckey = "'nyub'"
csecret = "'nyub'"
atoken = "-'nyub'"
asecret = "'nyub'"

class listener (StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(data)

            created_at = tweet ["created_at"]
            identity = tweet ["id"]
            text = tweet ["text"]
            status_reply = tweet ["in_reply_to_status_id"]
            user_reply = tweet ["in_reply_to_user_id"]
            screen_name_reply = tweet ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]

            user_id = tweet ["user"]["id"]
            user_screen_name = tweet["user"]["screen_name"]
            user_location = tweet["user"]["location"]
            user_url = tweet["user"]["url"]
            user_description = tweet["user"]["description"]
            user_followers = tweet["user"]["followers_count"]
            user_friends = tweet["user"]["friends_count"]
            user_statuses = tweet["user"]["statuses_count"]
            user_created = tweet["user"]["created_at"]
            user_lang =  tweet["user"]["lang"]

            coordinates = tweet ["coordinates"]
            place = tweet ["place"]
            rt_count = tweet ["retweet_count"]
            fav_count = tweet ["favorite_count"]

            hashtags = []

            for hashtag in tweet ["entities"]["hashtags"]:
                hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])

            urls = []

            for url in tweet ["entities"]["urls"]:
                urls.append(url["expanded_url"])

            c.execute ("INSERT INTO luck (timestamp, tweet_created_at, tweet_id, tweet_text, in_reply_status, in_reply_user_id, in_reply_screen_name, user_id, user_screen_name, user_location, user_url, user_description, user_followers_count, user_friends_count, users_statuses_count, user_created_at, user_lang, tweet_coords, tweet_place, tweet_retweet_count, tweet_fav_count, hashtags, urls) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                       ((time.time()), created_at, identity, text, status_reply, user_reply, screen_name_reply, user_id, user_screen_name, user_location, user_url, user_description, user_followers, user_friends, user_statuses, user_created, user_lang, coordinates, place, rt_count, fav_count, str(hashtags), str(urls)))

            conn.commit ()

            print (text)

            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print "failed on data", str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error (self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["#מזל_טוב"])
```

Comment: You probably need to set the encoding for the file:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/729016/748858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this as the first line of your python file(or second if you use it with a #/bin/bash)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and use this

```
u"#מזל_טוב" # Unicode string in python 2.7
```

instead of

```
"#מזל_טוב"
```

the later only works in python 3

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the beginning of your script (very first line):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and of course make sure it's actually saved in utf-8.