# Scrapy and xpath find <a> with the text "»"

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider, which has to find the «next» link —the one with the "»" inside— from this HTML:

```
<div id="content-center">
    <div class="paginador">
      <span class="current">01</span>
      <a href="ml=0">02</a>
      <a href="ml=0">03</a>
      <a href="ml=0">04</a>
      <a href="ml=0">»</a>
      <a href="ml=0">Last</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying with this spider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "***"
    start_urls = [
    'http://www.***.com/10000000000177/',
    ]
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.***.com/"]
    def parse(self, response):
        s = Selector(response)
        page_list_urls = s.css('#content-center > div.listado_libros.gwe_libros > div > form > dl.dublincore > dd.title > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in page_list_urls:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        next_page = hxs.select(u"//*[@id='content-center']/div[@class='paginador']/a[text()='\u00bb']/@href").extract()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        for each_book in response.css('div#container'):
            yield {
                'title': each_book.css('div#content > div#primary > div > h1.title-book::text').extract(),
            }
```

Does not recognize the link, any idea?
Any Idea how to solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: How about declaring the string inside `select` Unicode, i.e. `u'//a[text()='»']/@href'`?

Comment: You are aware that you are defining two strings with `»` as an operator, right? Or is that just an error in the markup of this question? If thats the case this should work for you: `"//a[text()='»']/@href"`

Comment: Try to use workaround `//a[.="Last"]/preceding-sibling::a[position()=1]`

Comment: @severin, I don't understand: which two strings? @tomas, `u'//a[text()='»']/@href'` returns the same message…

Comment: @Andersson, I can't use the position because then it will never find the end… Quotes corrected

Comment: @Nikita, *end*? You mean that `"Last"` button is absent on the last page or what?

Comment: Yes, in the last page there is no link with `»`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use the `\u`-escaped version of `»`:

```
>>> print(u'\u00bb')
»
```

like this in your `.xpath()` call (**note the `u"..."` prefix** for the string parameter):

```
hxs.select(u"//a[text()='\u00bb']/@href").extract()
```

Your spider .py file is probably using UTF-8:

```
>>> u'\u00bb'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc2\xbb'
```

so you can also use `hxs.select(u"//a[text()='»']/@href").extract()` (the `u"..."` prefix is still there), but you also need to tell Python what your `.py` encoding is.

One usually does that with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (or equivalent) at the top of the .py file (first line for example).

You can read more on Python source code encoding declarations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations).

Comment: Hi @paul. If I add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the beggining of the spider, and then the `u` prefix, It returns an error with the `»`…

Comment: Can you share the error (through pastebin perhaps)? did you try the `\u00bb` way? Also note comment from @Severin above, `'//a[text()='»']/@href'` should really be `u'//a[text()="»"]/@href'` or `u"//a[text()='»']/@href"`

Comment: Ok, I added the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and the full xpath `"u//div[@id='content-center']/div[@class='paginador']/a[text()='\u00bb']/@href"` and now it doesn't gives any error. But it doesn't find the link. Is it correct? updated the question!

Comment: `u` is to be pre-pended to what's in quotes: `u"//div[@id='content-center']/div[@class='paginador']/a[text‌​()='\u00bb']/@href"`, not `"u//div[..."`

Comment: Corrected! but it still can't see the link…, question updated!

Comment: It's hard to help you because `//div[@id='content-center']/div[@class='paginador']` does not match your sample HTML

Comment: Ok, I just realised that with your solution the spider finds the link, the encoding and `\u00bb` did the trick. The problem now is not there: although the spider finds the link, it doesn't follow it, don't know why. But this is another question… Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) will do the job

```
data = '''
<div class="pages">
  <span class="current">01</span>
  <a href="ml=0">02</a>
  <a href="ml=0">03</a>
  <a href="ml=0">04</a>
  <a href="ml=0">05</a>
  <a href="ml=0">06</a>
  <a href="ml=0">07</a>
  <a href="ml=0">08</a>
  <a href="ml=0">09</a>
  <a href="ml=0">10</a>
  <a href="ml=0">»</a>
  <a href="ml=0">Last</a>
</div>

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for a in bsobj.find_all('a'):
   if a.text == '»':
      print(a['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks @ksai. I imagine `bs4 import BeautifulSoup ` goes in the head of the class, and the rest inside it, just after `allowed_domains = ["http://www.*****.com/"]. Added full code to avoid confusions.
`

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could change on your code:

1. You don't need to create/import Selector, the response object has both .css() and .xpath methods which are shortcuts to selector. [Docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.xpath)
2. HtmlXPathSelector is depracated, you should user selector's(or rather response's) .xpath() method
3. .extract() will yield a array of urls, so you will not be able to call a request on the array, you should use extract_first() here

Applying these points:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request


class YourCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "***"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.***.com/10000000000177/',
    ]
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.***.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        page_list_urls = response.css('#content-center > div.listado_libros.gwe_libros > div > form > dl.dublincore > dd.title > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in page_list_urls:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_following_urls, dont_filter=True)
        next_page = response.xpath(u"//*[@id='content-center']/div[@class='paginador']/a[text()='\u00bb']/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_following_urls(self, response):
        for each_book in response.css('div#container'):
            yield {
                'title': each_book.css('div#content > div#primary > div > h1.title-book::text').extract(),
            }
```