# Calling .py script via ajax , encoding problem

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, encoding

I am trying to get proper response from .py script via jquery ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
                              url:'./pyscripts/word_zakup_odluka.py',
                              type:'POST',
                              datatype:'json',
                              data:JSON.stringify(json_odluka),
                              success:function(response){
                                pythonresponse=response['message']
                              }
                            })
```

.py script

```
print("Content-Type: application/json\n\n")
json_odluka=json.load(sys.stdin)
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps({'success:'true','message':json_odluka},indent=1))
sys.stdout.close()
```

Object I send via ajax is:

```
{opcinegrada: "općine ", opcinagrad: "općina ", opcinigradu: "općini ", opcinskogradsko: "općinsko", klasasuglasnost: "", …}
```

And I want to get the same object with ć character but instead I get:

```
{opcinegrada: "opÄ‡ine ", opcinagrad: "opÄ‡ina ", opcinigradu: "opÄ‡ini ", opcinskogradsko: "opÄ‡insko", klasasuglasnost: "", …}
```

Where and how can I set proper encoding in this case? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Set the python script to handle utf8 characters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163461/4535200

Comment: Also, are you using Python2 or python3?

Comment: @Torxed python3

Comment: @Qirel tried with line # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, still doesn't work

Comment: Did you include both those lines? What is the encoding of the actual files here, Python and JS?

Comment: @Qirel utf-8 for both, 
#!C:/Users/Korisnik/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe
# coding=utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
I included these three lines