# python utf-8 encoding declaration

Tags: python, encoding

é character belongs to utf-8 as shown in:

https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

As official documentation (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)
 says:

'In Python 2.1, Unicode literals can only be written using the Latin-1 based encoding "unicode-escape"....'

I use Python 2.7.13

so in my code (as told in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), I have tried successively (after #!/usr/bin/python)

```
# coding=utf-8

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

the last one also appears in the post solution [Correct way to define Python source code encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding)

but it still does not work:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ./<file_name>.py on line 160, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Any ideas folks ?? thanx.

Comment: Works for me.  Can you share an [mcve] please?

Comment: "é character belongs to utf-8": not exactly. UTF-8 is a character encoding that can encode the entire Unicode character set. é is a member of the Unicode character set.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: `import unittest`

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select.....`

Comment: [...some more imports ]

Comment: `if driver.title == 'Déposer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx':`

Comment: [... some more code]

Comment: sorry but <br /> does not work, so I put a comment for each line.