# An Error on jupyter notebook Saying "500 : illegal multibyte sequence"

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, multibyte

[image: Jupyter notebook showing "500 : illegal multibyte sequence"]

I get this error and cannot open every Jupyter notebook file.

Contrary, I can open `http://localhost:8888/tree/Downloads`.

It seems that this error started happening after I tried to install a library via pip or upgrade pip even though I had been using Jupyter notebook on Anaconda.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like some encoding issue. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/728891/2750819.

Comment: Hi masa. I think this could be happening because of the change in locales. What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on windows 10. I already uninstalled Anaconda and installed python solely. Still have this issue.