# Hello world in pythonwin with unicode, does not work

Tags: python, unicode

Using pythonwin (i have version 3.6.8 pywin32 build224.0 from 2018)
write:

```
print("Hello world, I make £10000 per month")
```

or what I originally tested

```
print("Hej världen")
```

which is Swedish (my language) for "hello world" (the £10000 is an example and not my salary)

Save as a file.
Close and reopen it and run it.
There is a fault message:

> Failed to run script - syntax error (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 22: invalid start byte (helloworld£10000.py)

It seems that the editor uses Latin-1 and the python interpreter uses utf-8.

Using notepad to save it as UTF-8 and reopen in pythonwin allows running but the source becomes: `Hello world, I make Â£10000 per month`

This has to be a frequent problem but I can't find a good way of handling it for pythonwin. Neither in help or on stackoverflow.
I saw a discussion on the issue on unicode in pythonwin is from 2003 and I don't understand why this is a problem now.

Comment: Python use UTF-8 as default (you can use magic codes at beginning of file to change interpretation. Then the second problem: you use print, and print in windows will use system code page (Windows is the only large OS which it is not using UTF-8 as default). So you should search this forum on how to print UTF-8 (so setting terminal or using other terminal so that they are UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

`Pythonwin` in older versions of `pywin32` saved in the localized ANSI encoding unless a `#coding:` comment specifies something else.  `Pythonwin` reads that comment and saves in the encoding declared, but note I encountered at least one older version that was buggy about that as well.  For UTF-8 use:

`#coding: utf8`

Ideally, use the [latest version](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) (301 at this writing), which defaults to UTF-8.

If you install/upgrade via `pip` as in `pip install -U pywin32` make sure to open an administrator prompt and run `Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install` if you want things like `import win32com` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Close the file in pythonwin.
In windows 10 open in notepad and save as "UTF-8 with BOM" (I have that).
In windows 7 open in notepad and save as "UTF-8".

This will save as UTF-8 with Byte Order Mark.
Open in Pythonwin, should work now. .
You can even use non-latin like Russian, e.g. print("Привет") now, which the editor does not accept by default (latin-1).

Pythonwin does not save in UTF-8 even with non-latin letters present, unless there is a UTF8-BOM present, and there's no option in my version to save as UTF-8.

Comment: Actually sometimes this does not work. 
Sometimes pythonwin says Syntax error in line 1, even if line 1 is perfect or empty.

I found that you can write in line 1
# coding: utf-8
or
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding
Which is 12 years old. 
Why did pythonwin (3 years ago) still have this bug so you can't write Hello World except in English.